# SU Retag Request: [partition*] --> [partion(ing)]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Sorry to bother once again, but while evaluating the tags on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/235721/how-do-i-shrink-my-partition-on-windows) I came up with another one:

- [partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition)
- [partitioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitioning)
- [partition-scheme](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-scheme) (Doesn't need a separate tag imo)
- [disk-partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-partition) (Partition(ing) is used for this already)
- [partitioning-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitioning-software) (Partitioning is not hardware, so software is likely inherent)

All those tags can be housed in either [partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition) or [partitioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) (I prefer the second one, it's action-wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged everything into [partitioning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) and created synonyms for all the rest.